# How to return a copy of the data in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to return a new copy of the data in a C++ Template class. The following code is getting this error: `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'`. If I remove the `new T` then I am not returning a copy of the data but a pointer to it.

```
template<class T>
T OrderedList<T>::get( int k )
{
    Node<T>* n = list;
    for( int i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        n=n->get_link();
    }
    return new T( n->get_data() ); // This line is getting the error **********
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`new` creates and returns a pointer. You just want a *copy* which will be created implicitly, since the return statement will invoke the copy constructor (or equivalent for POD) of the object `T`:

```
return n->get_data();
```

Comment: Or, depending on the definition of `Node<>` and `T`, `return T( n->get_data() )`. (Although I agree that it is unlikely given this code.)

Comment: @sbi: since the function returns a 'T', I cant imagine what sort of 'Node<>' and 'T' would compile and fail to copy the 'T'